# Is there a way to asynchronously upload build to testflight using fastlane?

Tags: fastlane

We have several white-labeled applications, which are updated usually simultaneously. Right now, we have a Fastlane script, which just builds one of the versions and uploads it. We used to run it several times to upload all the versions, one after another.

My idea is to build all the apps without waiting for the previous upload finishes. The script I'm trying to run looks like this:

```
lane :build_all_testflight do
    all_uploads = []

    disable_automatic_code_signing(path: xcodeproj_path)

    section_id = "[v#{get_version_number(xcodeproj: xcodeproj_path)}]"
    changelog_for_current_version = read_changelog(
        changelog_path: changelog_path,
        section_identifier: section_id
    )

    prepare_build_directory()

    variants.keys.each do |variant|
        build(variant: variant, export_method: "app-store")

        all_uploads << Thread.new do # Here I'm trying to just start a new thread with uploading
            upload_to_testflight(wait_for_uploaded_build: true, changelog: changelog_for_current_version)
        end
    end

    enable_automatic_code_signing(path: xcodeproj_path)

    all_uploads.each do |thread|
        thread.join
    end
end
```

It seems, that it doesn't fail, but builds are not showing on appstore connect. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a recommended way of doing it?